# How to use Spring Data MongoDB repository to insert document so it appears on the Documents tab in MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have defined a Spring Data MongoDb repository (spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb version 3.0.3) like this :

```
public interface WorkflowRepository extends MongoRepository<PersistentWorkflowState, String> {
}
```

I use this repository to insert a "document" like this :

```
 inserted = workflowRepository.insert(mydoc);
```

Afterwards when I use MongoDB Compass version 1.36.4 to look at the result the "Documents" tab is always empty but I do find my inserted document in the "Aggregations" tab :[image]

I find this behaviour confusing because I first tought my insert failed.  I didn't even think to look at the "Aggregations" tab at first and only accidentally discovered my inserted "document" appeared on the Aggregations tab instead of on the "Documents" tab.

Why is this happening ?
What do I need to do to get my document appear on the "Documents" tab ?
I only do a "simple insert".  No calculations (read "aggregations") of any kind.  So why is my insert considered to be an "aggregation" ?

I expect the data inserted by my repository (a simply crud operation) to appear on the Documents tab in MongoDB Compass.

UPDATE : [user20042973](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20042973/user20042973) Thanks ! Apparently the inserted document is immediately visible on the Aggregations tab without clicking on anything at all.  However, for the inserted document to become visible on the Documents tab an initial click on the Find or Refresh Documents button is needed.  Afterwards, even when closing the connection to the database and reconnecting the inserted document is immediately visible on the Documents tab even without clicking on the Find or Refresh Documents button.
A nice "gotcha" if you ask me :-)

Regards,
Ronald

Comment: You don't see it in the Documents tab even after you hit the `Find` button again?